# Static Method C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, methods

I am new in C++ and I have a basic question for you. It must be basic, I think... :) .

Here is the code that I expect to work but it does not.

```
char* deneme = Tool::getStringIntoArray("Hello");
```

I want to get an char array from a static function in the class 'Tool' by passing a string into it.

Here is my Tool header:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef TOOL_H_
#define TOOL_H_

class Tool
{
public:
    static char* getStringIntoArray(string);
};

#endif
```

I have learnt that the only thing to use that function is to give a keyword which is 'static' there.

Finally, the Tool.cpp for the function:

```
#include "Tool.h"

char* getStringIntoArray(string str)
{
    int* size = new int(str.size());
    char* array;
    array = new char[*size];

    for ( int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        array[i] = str[i];
    }

    delete size;
    return array;
}
```

Nevertheless it works in the source file where the first code that I gave but when I put this function into a class for static usage, it does not work. The error is shown below :

```
undefined reference to `Tool::getStringIntoArray(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
```

Thx.

Comment: It's best to avoid dynamic allocation where possible; `size` should be an automatic variable (`int size = str.size();`) since it doesn't need to outlive the function. `array` still needs to be dynamic, but make sure that anyone who calls the function remembers to `delete[]` it when they're finished; or return a `vector<char>` or `unique_ptr<char[]>` so that it's deleted automatically.

Comment: @Rapptz: That gives you `const char*`, not `char*`. There's no defined way to get a mutable pointer to the contents of a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined reference to `Tool::getStringIntoArray(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'

It's looking for `Tool::getStringIntoArray` but you defined `getStringIntoArray`.

Change the signature in the definition from

```
char* getStringIntoArray(string str)
```

to

```
char* Tool::getStringIntoArray(string str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be `char* Tool::getStringIntoArray(string str)`.

Your version just defines a free function, not the one in the class.

Also, you should pass the `string` by const reference:

```
char* Tool::getStringIntoArray(const std::string& str)
```

Also

```
using namespace std;
```

is bad practice (even moreso in a header). Favor type qualification (`std::`) instead.

**Also**

```
int* size = new int(str.size());
char* array;
array = new char[*size];
```

is bad. Just create an `int` -

```
int size = str.size(); 
array = new char[size]
```

You don't need a pointer for that.

Comment: At the beginning it was a stupid error but I liked to see that interest to my code. I do not think to do that right now. Forget about the removing :) It is great to see that spirit.

Comment: it must be a pointer for the size because that method is going to be run more than one. I could not understand why I need to make it not a pointer.

Comment: using namespace td isn't that bad a practice. However 'using namespace' in a global context in a header is a fast route to all sorts of grief and should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @ErayTuncer What do you mean? The method running more than once or not has nothing to do with it. Making size a pointer is unnecessary. Unnecessary pointers are bad practice for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify the class name, you forgot that:

```
char* Tool::getStringIntoArray(string str)
{

}
```